# Fastest way to copy feature dataset from ArcSDE to File Geodatabase in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, enterprise-geodatabase, performance

What geoprocessing tool is the fastest for copying feature datasets from ArcSDE to a file geodatabase?

I want to make a model in ModelBuilder that copies an entire featuredataset from my SDE database to a file geodatabase. I don't know what the fastest tool is. I tried "Copy element" but that is painstakingly slow compared to if you copy-pasting in ArcCatalog. Featureclass to Geodatabase, only copies the featureclasses in the dataset, and places them in the root of the fgdb. Featureclass to featureclass is a lot of drag and dropping, and I don't know about the speed.

Comment: do you mean with "Copy element" as `arcpy.Copy_management(in_data, out_data)`?

Comment: @Aragon, Actually, Im not sure. But I'll convert the model to python and see.

Comment: @Aragon, Yes it was Copy_management(in_data, out_data)

Comment: @Aragon. The tool is much, much faster in python than in ModelBuilder... why???

Comment: ModelBuilder is likely to have a layer or several of abstraction above the Python. Its the price you pay for a pretty interface unfortunately.

Comment: @GIS-Jonathan, i don't know about pretty... but easy to use :-)

Comment: What are the actual timings on copying via the Catalog window, using the Copy tool dialog, and embedding Copy into Python and ModelBuilder?  I know Catalog window is always quickest because it already knows it has a license and does not have to check that first.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I haven't timed it. But it is several times faster with catalog and python than ModelBuilder. The difference between ArcCatalog and Python seems to be insignificant.

Comment: Appending to an empty Geodatabase might be faster, has proved to be in the past on large projects. All depends on the current ArcSDE setup.

Answer (score 0):

Consensus from the comments seems to be that this may depend on a number of factors.

Consequently, in order to be sure what the fastest is in your configuration, I think the best option will be for you to try the various ways that you have found that it is possible to perform the copy, and then to time them.